# Failed POST call

Tags: java, rest, servlets, post

I'm making a POST call from within Java, and I'm not sure why it's not going through. The code is as follows:

```
String screencastStartURL = "......";                            
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);   
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateID", s_id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startTime", screencastStartTime));   
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identifier", screencastId));
System.out.println("about to make postCall"); 
String postResponse = Commons.postCall(screencastStartURL, nameValuePairs);
out.println(postResponse); // out is an earlier instantiated PrintWriter
```

The `postCall` method is as follows:

```
public static String postCall(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)   {
        System.out.println("Within postCall method");
        String ans = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
          System.out.println("Within postCall method 2");
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

          ans = (EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ans;
    }
```

When I deploy this code on my Tomcat Server, it prints `about to make postCall` in the terminal, which means it successfully executes till before the POST call is made. But then, it doesn't print `Within postCall method` which means something goes wrong in the call itself?

The error message that I see is a `NullPointerException` which causes a `ServletException`

**Edit**

However when I make the POST call using the POSTMAN Rest Client Chrome App, it goes through successfully.

**Second Edit**

The stack trace that I see in my browser is

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.bl.apps.MemoLocalRecorder.App.doGet(App.java:121)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    com.bl.util.Commons.setURL(Commons.java:221)
    com.bl.util.Commons.<clinit>(Commons.java:150)
    com.bl.apps.MemoLocalRecorder.App.doGet(App.java:121)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Perhaps `Commons` is null?. Sorry, it's a static method. I'll withdraw the comment.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: String postResponse = Commons.postCall(screencastStartURL, nameValuePairs);

Comment: @JonnyHenly out is actually a `PrintWriter` object, earlier instantiated as `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();`
@BharathRallapalli I do not get what you mean. You've posted the same line as mine.

Comment: Forgot to add = operator in the line Commons.postCall(screencastStartURL, nameValuePairs); ?

Comment: @wrahool there is no "=" in your code at this particular line , i added it and commented the same

Comment: @BharathRallapalli my bad. I copied it wrongly. It's present actually. Edited the question.

Comment: are there any `static` blocks in your code , because the error thrown is because of any problem in static variable intialization

Comment: `Commons.postCall` is a `static` method. If that clarifies.

Comment: @BharathRallapalli thanks, the issue was with a static block, and static member initialization. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the stack trace you posted. the error is basically because of any exception in static variable initialization in static block

below is some info and some links to give more light on this

> On seeing the name of the exception you may be able to guess that this
>   exception is related to initialization of a variable.Yes of course
>   this error is related to the initialization of a static variables.The
>   variable may be of primitive type or user defined type.You might all
>   have known about the static initializer of a class.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-how-to-handle-exception-initializer-error/

http://craftingjava.blogspot.in/2012/06/javalangexceptionininitializererror.html